# How to Force Refresh Texture2D/Sprite when Programmically Modified using Editor Script?

Tags: unity, sprites, editors

Here is some code called using a custom button in the component inspector:

```
// created off-screen:
// Texture = Texture2D, width = int, height = int

SpriteRenderer.sprite = Sprite.Create(Texture, new Rect(0, 0, width, height), new Vector2(0, 0));
```

Long story short, I am programmatically creating a Texture2D and applying it to my SpriteRenderer. I 100% know the code works because, once I run the game, the SpriteRenderer displays the exact Texture2D I programmatically created. The issue is when I click my "generate" button in the component inspector, the texture is not displayed in the scene.

When I click on my SpriteRenderer in the inspector, I can see a "box" representing the texture's bounds as if it's not loaded? The size changes for each generation, so I know it knows the size of the texture? But I can't find a way to force it load except for actually running the game. Once I run the game, the texture displays just fine. Even after I stop the game, the editor shows the texture just fine until I generate it again. As if there's something about running the game that refreshes it?

Is there something I'm missing? Something to force the scene or SpriteRenderer to display in editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to call `Texture2D.Apply()` after modifying the texture using `SetPixel`. Whoops.